# Want to Add Custom Fields for Uploading video to WordPress Users from front end

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, users, user-meta

I am trying to an add upload media option for the user profile.Which i was achieved with the help of [This Link](http://www.flyinghippo.com/blog/adding-custom-fields-uploading-images-wordpress-users/)

By adding the code given in the above link on my theme's functions.php i am able to see the extra added field on user profile section once i logged in with admin screen.

**What I want is** :I want to show the upload media option for the front-end  user to add their video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CMB2 library for Custom Field

https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2/wiki/Adding-your-own-field-types

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to try to integrate wp-admin components to the front end of your site, It is easier, more reliable and more maintanable to simply create an upload form for the frontend of the site.

In fact, as soon as I [googled it](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=adding+a+media+upload+for+for+logged+in+users+wordpress&*) I found there is already a [plugin](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-file-upload/) to do exactly that. It looks to have solid ratings, many active installs and actively maintained.

Im sure extending this plugin to display a video the user uploaded to the site wouldn't be too much of an issue.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your quick reply.But here in my website their is front end from for user that front-end from already have some fields and i want to add this upload video field with this existing fields.